# Merge dependent observables

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2

I have two `Observable`s that emit the same type of data. But both of them depend on the last value emitted by the other for their scan operator as initial value. I need to merge them. I can't make one subscribe to the other because my `Observable`s are triggered by different values. I'm thinking subjects should be involved but I'm not sure how.

```
val intents: Observable<Intent> = ...

intents
  .scan(MyViewState.default(), intentToStateReducer)

intents
  .map(intentToActionMapper)
  .compose(actionDispatcher)
  .scan(MyViewState.default(), resultToStateReducer)
```

The two `Observable`s will maintain their own states. Merging wil not make them see each others latest value. New states from each `Observable` will be based on the previous value of its own stream.

Comment: Can you clarify your question with sample code?

Comment: @GVillani82 added

Comment: You need to provide more examples of the data you have as input and what you want as output. As of this writing, your code doesn't match your narrative. It is especially not clear how the two observables can depend on each other's initial values, and what that means.

Comment: You state "both of them depend on the *last* value emitted by the other". This is an impossible condition. Can you please restate your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
    final String[] aStrings = {"A1", "A2", "A3", "A4"};
    final String[] bStrings = {"B1", "B2", "B3"};

    final Observable<String> aObservable = Observable.fromArray(aStrings);
    final Observable<String> bObservable = Observable.fromArray(bStrings);

    Observable.merge(aObservable, bObservable)
            .subscribe(getObserver());
```

Using merge operator to combine Observable : merge does not maintain the order of Observable. It will emit all the 7 values may not be in order.
Ex - "A1", "B1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "B2", "B3" - may be anything